# Devices disconnect while debugging iOS multipeer app

Tags: ios, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

I am working on an iOS multipeer app. Is there any easier way to debug multipeer app? When I run my app in a debugger, as stepping over statements take time devices get disconnected. Any suggestion how can I debug my multipeer app?